# Angular 4 Material http service not getting called

Tags: angular, rest, angular-material2

I am trying to call my rest service from angular which is running on other server, and populate the table using angular material, i have gone through How to use md-table with services in Angular 4 and  Angular 4 material table does not get populated tried in below procedure

**Component:**

```
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild,ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { WellService } from '../services/well.service';
import { Well } from '../well/well';
import {  Observable  } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { BehaviorSubject } from  'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/merge';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-well',
  templateUrl: './well.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./well.component.css'],
  providers:[WellService]
})



export class WellComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Wells';
  header:string;
  displayedColumns = ['active', 'company', 'country', 'well','wellbore'];
  public wellDatabase : WellDatabase | any;
  public wellDataSource: WellDataSource | any;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator : MatPaginator;

  constructor(private wellService:WellService,private changeDetector:ChangeDetectorRef) {

    this.header='assets/images/BHI_header_logo_bd.png'  

   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.wellDataSource = new WellDataSource(this.wellDatabase,this.paginator);
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
    console.log(this.wellDataSource);
  }

}
export class WellDatabase  {

  dataChange: BehaviorSubject<Well[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Well[]>([]);
  get data(): Well[] { return this.dataChange.value }

  constructor(private wellService: WellService) {
    this.getWells();
  }
getWells(){
  this.wellService.getWells().subscribe( response => {
    this.dataChange.next(response);
});
}






}
export class WellDataSource extends DataSource<any> {

  constructor(private _wellDatabase : WellDatabase, private _paginator: MatPaginator){
    super();
  }

  connect(): Observable<Well[]> {

const displayDataChanges = [
      this._wellDatabase.dataChange,
      this._paginator.page
    ];
    return Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges).map(() => {
      const data = this._wellDatabase.data.slice();
      const startIndex = this._paginator.pageIndex * this._paginator.pageSize;
      return data.splice(startIndex, this._paginator.pageSize);
    })
  }

  disconnect() {}
}
```

**Service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response  } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable,Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';  
import { Well } from '../well/well';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
@Injectable()
export class WellService {


  constructor(private  http:Http) { }
public getWells(): Observable < Well[] > {  
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/auth/testuser1/pass').map((response: Response) => {  
        return <Well[] > response.json().wellList;  
    }).catch(this.handleError);  
}  
//    
private handleError(errorResponse: Response) {  
    console.log(errorResponse.statusText);  
    return Observable.throw(errorResponse.json().error || "Server error");  
}  
private getHeaders(){
    // I included these headers because otherwise FireFox
    // will request text/html instead of application/json
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    return headers;
  }

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div style="text-align:center">  
  <div><img width="1100" [src]="header" margin-top:-40px></div>
   <div> 
        <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">



    <!-- Active -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="active">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Active </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.well.active}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Company -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="company">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Company </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.company}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Country -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="country">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Country</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.well.country}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Well -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="well">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Well </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.well}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>


        <!-- Wellbore -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="wellbore">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Wellbore </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.well.wellbore}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>


  <mat-paginator #paginator
  [length]="wellDataSource.length"
  [pageIndex]="0"
  [pageSize]="25"
  [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">
</mat-paginator>



          </div>           
</div>
```

i am able to see my HTTP service is not being called, the procedure i am following correct or not can any one guide me in this aspect.

The json response looks like below:
{"wellList":[{"country":"USA","well":"HBASE WELL","wellbore":"HBASE WELLBORE","company":"BAKER HUGHES","active":"-1"},{"country":"USA","well":"CurveEntWell","wellbore":"CurveEntWellBore","company":"BAKER HUGHES","active":"-1"},{"country":"USA","well":"20Feb17Well",
"wellbore":"20Feb17Wellbore2","company":"BAKER HUGHES","active":"-1"}]}

Comment: There's too much code in your question. Narrow it down to a more reproducable example. Are any errors thrown?

Comment: There are no errors in console, in order to get clear or understand any one my problem clearly i have added all my code stuff there, suggest me how can i narrow it

Answer (score 1):

You are overcomplicating things, you do not need `WellDatabase` since we are getting "real" data. So what you do, is get the data in the component, store it in an observable, and pass that observable to your `WellDataSource`.

Please do name (AND type) the variables better than I have below ;)

```ts
public dataSource: WellDataSource | any;
obs: any;

ngOnInit() {
  this.obs = this.wellService.getWells();
  this.dataSource = new WellDataSource(this.obs, this.paginator);
}
```

Then your `WellDataSource`:

```ts
constructor(private _obs: any, private _paginator: MatPaginator) {
  super();
}

connect(): Observable<any[]> {
  const displayDataChanges = [
    this._obs,
    this._paginator.page,
  ];

  return this._obs.flatMap(x => {
    return Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges).map(() => {
      const data = x.slice();
      const startIndex = this._paginator.pageIndex * this._paginator.pageSize;
      return data.splice(startIndex, this._paginator.pageSize);
    });
  })
}
```

also you have an error in your html, it should be

```ts
[length]="dataSource._obs.value.length"
```

instead of

```ts
[length]="wellDataSource.length"
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yxrz8r?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: Thanks for your help, but no luck not working still getting same blank output and also not able to see errors on console.

Comment: Well, compare your code to the plunker and also make sure that you are receiving data. How does the response look like in your network tab?

Comment: Yes, the service is being called and it is receiving data but it is not getting displayed.

Comment: How does your data look like? could you paste the JSON response to your question?

Comment: I have added the response to question, kindly please check.

Comment: Please check the demo (I had the wrong one before), it works fine there. You need to compare your code there. Also you had an error in your template. Check that one as well :)

Comment: its working Thank AJT_82 for your help, i have corrected my template its working fine thank you.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear! Please consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey tick under the voting of this answer, since it solved your issue :)

Comment: But one thing pagination is not coming correctly, unable to display next records.

Comment: Please console.log(dataSource) and check on which propertypath leads to the array length.

Comment: @SaiCharan, did you ever figure this one out? meaning the correct path :)

Answer (score 0):

try this sample code

```
//Component
getWells(){
    this.wellService.getWells()
          .then(data => {

            if (verifyResponse(data)) {
              // Success case area
              this.dataChange.next(response);
            } else {
              //Negative case area need to handle here
            }
          });
}

//Method to verify response data
verifyResponse(data){
    // verfiy accordingly and return flags
    if(){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

//Service
getWells(){
        return new Promise(resolve => {
           this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/auth/testuser1/pass' )
                    .subscribe(
                        data => {
                            resolve(data.wellList);                                 
                        }, error => {
                            resolve(false);                               
            });

        });
}
```

Comment: getting error on this line this.dataChange.next(response); i have tried declaring response object also but it is  not accepting.

Comment: What you want to do in that success case area?